# Insert numbers to array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I need to insert for every number sum of his digits in array using pointer arithmetic. Auxiliary arrays are not allowed.

Example:

```
123, 456, 789
```

Output:

```
123, 6, 456, 15, 789, 24
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum_of_digits(int n){
    int sum=0;
    while(n!=0){
        sum=sum+n%10;
        n/=10;
    }
    return sum;
}

void add(int *arr, int n)
{
    int *p=arr, *y=arr+n*2-2,i;
    while(p++<arr+n);
    p-=2;
    while(p>arr)
    {
        *y=*p;
        *p=0;
        p--;
        y-=2;
    }
    p=arr;
    while(p<arr+n*2)
    {
        *(p+1)=sum_of_digits(*p);
        p+=2;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}

void main() {
    int arr[20]={123, 456, 789},n=3;
    add(arr,n*2);
}
```

This works correct, but I don't understand the part of code with pointers. Could you explain me how this works?

Comment: `int arr[] = {123, 456, 789}` is equivalent to `int arr[3] = {123, 456, 789}`. That is, your array will have only three elements. C doesn't have any kind of dynamic arrays, you have to explicitly use dynamic memory allocation and reallocation for your own implementation of "dynamic arrays".

Comment: this can be (and that is requirement) solved using pointer arithmetic, dynamical allocation is not required

Comment: No it can't be solved using only pointer arithmetic (you're already doing pointer arithmetic when you index an array, for any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is exactly equal to `*(a + i)`). Arrays (not VLA's) have a size that is fixed at compile-time, such an array can't be extended or added to. If you go out of bounds of the array you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: For your use-case, you can solve it by explicitly setting the array size to the double of what you use to initialize it. So `int arr[6] = { 123, 456, 789 }` But then I would recommend initializing it with every other element as zero, so you don't have to move the existing numbers around (i.e. `int arr[6] = { 123, 0, 456, 0, 789, 0 }`, and then loop like `for (unsigned i = 0; i < n * 2; i += 2) { arr[i + 1] = sum_of_digits(arr[i]); }`)

Comment: thanks, btw I only know that it will be ten elements, they should be entered by user

Comment: As already mentioned you need to declare the array `int arr[6] ...` in your case, or more generally the array must have enough room so the numbers can be inserted. Also the algorithm in`add` function is wrong. Write an auxiliary function `printArr(int arr[], int n)` that prints the whole array `arr` and call it at the end of the outer for loop in `add` or where ever you think it's appropriate. Then you can see how `arr` evolves and you'll find out what's wrong. A piece of paper and a pencil may also be helpful here. Also learning the basics of your debugger also will help you greatly here.

Comment: If the user should input ten numbers, then you need 20 elements in your array, to fit the user input as well as the sums. And as for the input itself, I recommend you initialize the array to all zeros, and then input to every second element, so you don't have to shuffle the data around afterward.

Comment: Lastly a note about arrays and pointers. When declared as an argument, `int arr[]` is really the same as `int *arr`. That is, `arr` is a pointer. And as I mentioned earlier, even "array index" syntax will really be done as pointer arithmetic, especially if you're working with actual pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited code, now it works, could you explain me how this works? I don't understand even though it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have formatted function `add` and added some comments to explain it, I hope they clarify what's happening.
Note that `arr[i] == *(arr + i)` and `*arr == arr[0]`

```
void add(int *arr, int n)
{
    // p points to last number in arr
    // Equivalent to &arr[n-1]
    int *p = arr + n - 1;
    
    // y points to where last number will be after spreading
    // Equivalent to &arr[2*n - 2]
    int *y = arr + n * 2 - 2;
    
    // for n = 4 arr looks like this
    // [A, B, C, D, _, _, _, _]
    //           ^           ^
    //           p           y
    
    // Spread numbers of arr
    // [A, B, C, D, _, _, _, _] -> [A, _, B, _, C, _, D, _]
    while (p > arr)
    {
        // Copy D to last position
        *y = *p;
        // Zero original D location, unnecessary
        *p = 0;
        // Move p backwards by one
        p--;
        // Move y backwards by two
        y -= 2;
        
        // arr now looks like this
        // [A, B, C, _, _, _, D, _]
        //        ^     ^   
        //        p     y
        
        // After next iteration
        // [A, B, _, _, C, _, D, _]
        //     ^  ^         
        //     p  y      
        
        // After next iteration
        // [A, _, B, _, C, _, D, _]
    }
    
    // Iterate over every other value 
    // and assign arr[i+1] to sum_of_digits[i]
    p = arr;
    while (p < arr + n * 2)
    {
        *(p + 1) = sum_of_digits(*p);
        p += 2;
    }
    // Equivalent to
    // for (int i = 0; i < n * 2; i += 2) {
    //     arr[i + 1] = sum_of_digits(arr[i]);
    // }
    
    // [A, sum_of_digits(A), B, sum_of_digits(B), C, sum_of_digits(C), 
    //  D, sum_of_digits(D)]

    // Print array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: so detailed and well explained :)